# Extracting down left corner in image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I got an binary image and i want to get the points of the left down corner of this photo:

[image: photo]

(the one where the red arrow points). In particular, i want to get the coordinates of that point.

EDIT:
I, have this [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2e7V8.jpg), and i want to get the x,y coordinates of the coins and get their position relative to the down left corner. Here is my code and what i've done so far.

```
    %% loading the image
A=imread('as.jpg');
figure, imshow(A);
K=rgb2gray(A);
I=imrotate(K,90);
[H,W]=size(I);
figure, imshow(I);
%%
[visina,sirina]=size(I);
sir=sirina(1)/5;
P1=I(:,1:sir);

%% cutting the photo in segments

podelba=4;
P=cell(podelba,1);
pomN=sir;
for n=1:4
    pomK=sir+pomN;
    P{n}=I(:,pomN:pomK);
    pomN=pomK;
end

W=imrotate(([P1 P{1} P{2} P{3} P{4} ]),0); 
figure, imshow(W);

%% threshold
g1=im2bw(P1,graythresh(P1));
podelba1=4;
G=cell(podelba,1);
for i=1:4
    G{i}=im2bw(P{i},graythresh(P{i}));
end

BW=~imrotate(([g1 G{1} G{2} G{3} G{4}]),0);
figure, imshow(BW);

%% noise reduction
bw=bwareaopen(BW,20);
se=strel('disk',2);
bw=imclose(bw,se);
bw=imrotate(imfill(bw,'holes'),-90);
figure, imshow(bw);

%%
[B,L] = bwboundaries(bw,'noholes');
figure, imshow(bw);
% Display the label matrix and draw each boundary
imshow(label2rgb(L, @jet, [.5 .5 .5]))
hold on
for k = 1:length(B)
  boundary = B{k};
  plot(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1), 'w', 'LineWidth', 2)
end
%%
stats = regionprops(L,'Area','Centroid');

threshold = 0.80;

% loop over the boundaries
for k = 1:length(B)

  % obtain (X,Y) boundary coordinates corresponding to label 'k'
  boundary = B{k};

  % compute a simple estimate of the object's perimeter
  delta_sq = diff(boundary).^2;
  perimeter = sum(sqrt(sum(delta_sq,2)));

  % obtain the area calculation corresponding to label 'k'
  area = stats(k).Area;

  % compute the roundness metric
  metric = 4*pi*area/perimeter^2;

  % display the results
  metric_string = sprintf('%2.2f',metric);

  % mark objects above the threshold with a black circle
  if metric > threshold
    centroid = stats(k).Centroid;
    plot(centroid(1),centroid(2),'ko');
  end

%     text(boundary(1,2)-35,boundary(1,1)+13,metric_string,'Color','y',...
%         'FontSize',14,'FontWeight','bold');

end
```

Comment: can you share what you've tried doing already? Also, do you want to get the points automatically or manually? If manually, try imtool (https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imtool.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox, you can use [`regionprops`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) to give you the centroid and list of pixels within each of the connected white regions of your image.

```
%// Load image and convert to binary
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAPB3.jpg');
img = img(:,:,1) > 50;

%// Determine centroids of each connected component
props = regionprops(img, {'Centroid', 'PixelIdxList'});

%// The lower left corner will have the centroid with the highest Y component
centroids = cat(1, props.Centroid);
[~, bottomLeftIdx] = max(centroids(:,2));

bottomLeft = props(bottomLeftIdx);
```

Now you can use `bottomLeft` to access the list of pixels that are contained within that block.

```
result = double(img);
result(bottomLeft.PixelIdxList) = 2;

imshow(result, [])
```

[image]

Comment: i uploaded my code, take a look again. Thanks a lot. :)